# Fragment manager Getting into custom adapter

Tags: android

In my Adapter I want to Navigate different fragments

```
  public NavAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavItems> navItems) {
    this.navItems = navItems;
    this.context = context;
   }
```

in above adapter Constructor I managed to get context , how to get the fragmentManager ?

Comment: Well you have to typecast the context to get Fragment manager , i suggest you to use SupportFragmantmanager instead of Fragment manager

Comment: Can you tell me the code snip for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  YourActivity mainActivity = (YourActivity) context;
  FragmentManager manager = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

You can use this to get FregmantManager and perform the transaction .